# i2p/Kovri fundamentals in Monero

Tags: privacy, kovri, i2p

Have the fundamental properties of Kovri been decided upon for Monero?

In particular, I'm curious about the IP configuration for the i2p/Kovri router. i.e. Will it be auto-detect methods, or hidden mode, etc.?

Hidden mode is the default in Tails i2p configuration, and I assume this is for increased anonymity. However, hidden mode can mean it takes a long time to integrate the router into the network. How will this be dealt with in Kovri, since users are likely to open the wallet just briefly to transact?

Keep up the awesome work devs.

Answer (score 9):

Kovri for all intents and purposes is dead and development towards an I2P Java Router lite alternative continues with [I2P-zero](https://github.com/i2p-zero/i2p-zero) and [tini2p](https://gitlab.com/tini2p/tini2p).

As of September 2, 2019, I2P via proxy is supported in Monero. To run in this mode, start `monerod` with the options `--proxy i2p,127.0.0.1:9000` (for outbound connections) and `--anonymous-inbound cmeua5767mz2q5jsaelk2rxhf67agrwuetaso5dzbenyzwlbkg2q.b32.i2p:5000,127.0.0.1:30000` (for inbound connections). See [ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md) for information.

Answer (score 3):

Kovri in Monero will be not using *hidden mode* and *disabled inbound connections* as default, since if everyone would do so, for obvious reasons it wouldn't be possible to build up a network. The [FAQ](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md) mentions these features only **to provide anonymity for those who live in countries with extreme conditions or those firewalled by carrier-grade NAT or DS-Lite**. However, you probably will be able to use them also from every other location if you think you should.

Additionally there will be an option to use [Pluggable Transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en) to obfuscate all traffic for users behind firewalls with Deep Packet Inspection.

All these features will probably have an impact on performance, so you should use them only when necessary. However, the i2p network overall has a better performance than TOR for example, since every node is a router per default.